# What is the best way to handle routing for CMS-like project in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, routes, doctrine

I'm trying to build an Symfony2 application, that have CMS features.
I've got three entities (among others) which are : `Page`, `Category`, `Post` (classic ones, huh ?)

I would like to have the following routing :

> Page : */{slug}* (slug is a Page entity field)
>
> Category : */{slug}* (slug is a Category entity field)
>
> Post : */{slug}* (slug is a Post entity field)

However, this will never work, because Symfony2 router, will match the first route that corresponds to the `/{slug}` pattern.

I would like to know, what is the best pratice to handle these cases. I'm aware of Symfony CMF, but I do not want use this kind of massive tool (as it contains too many bundles which I'm not willing to use).

Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a custom route loader to do this, check the cookbook article:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html

The CMF project uses its own dynamic router which you could use without the full CMF stack also:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/routing/dynamic.html

Comment: Thanks @gezpage. I've succeeded to make it work. However, with large quantity of Page, Category and Post entities, the cache:clear command is dropping errors. There's too many urls cached :

page_100 /my-slug
page_101 /my-slug2
page_102 /my-slug3
page_103 /my-slug4 ...

page_100 /my-slug